# What is the purpose of strange gear marks?

Tags: gears

I'm now looking at a clutchless [Hot Swapping Gear Mechanism](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2987778). Each gear assembly consists of 5 gears: three main gears and two intermediate (transitional between two main gears). Each gear has unique markings, the purpose of which I do not completely understand.

The first gear has two round marks on the top:

[image: Gear 1]

Then the intermediate gear between the first and the middle has one round mark on the top:

[image: Gear 1-to-2]

Finally, the last gear has three round marks on the bottom:

[image: Gear 3]

These look like timing marks to me and they are there to prevent incorrect assembly. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

The middle gear has a crescent mark on the top of one of its teeth:

[image: Gear 2]

And finally, the intermediate gear between the middle and the last has weird "chipped" marks on the top of two of its teeth:

[image: Gear 2-to-3]

The purpose of these marks is completely unclear to me. They might also be unintentional leftovers from the previous iterations of the design. Or since this design is prohibited to be sold, they might serve the function similar to of fictitious entries in dictionaries: if someone is caught selling this design, it can be identified by these marks that serve no purpose other than identification. They might also be additional timing marks, but this seems redundant, because this model is intended to be 3D-printed, so the whole gear assembly is solid and cannot be taken apart, just one timing mark on one of the gears should be sufficient.

Am I correct in identifying the circles in the first 3 pictures as timing marks? What could the marks in the last two pictures possibly be?

Comment: Are the centers really that offcenter?

Comment: @joojaa Yes, for main gears the center hole is perfectly centered, but for the intermediate gears the hole is offset.

Comment: then it might be for balancing

Comment: how are the gears arranged?

Comment: maybe the two chipped teeth on the last gear delimit a range where the crescent marked tooth should mesh

Comment: All the gears in the pictures are fixed to each other in a stack. The gear directly in contact with all of them doesn't have any markings.